# Trouble finding min in a 2D array with threads and trouble synchronizing threads

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading

I am new to threads and I have a threaded C program that is supposed to find the minimum of a 2D array (nxn) using a p number of threads.

However, when it comes to comparing the minimum of all the threads it produces a false minimum.

Do I have to use a semaphore in order to protect each minimum of each thread?

Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

long int part = 0;  

// structure for passing arguments
typedef struct dim
{
    int s, e; // s for start, e for end
    int n,p; // n board size , p number of threads
    int mat[100][100]; //board
    int minf[100]; // board that stores the mins of each thread
}dim;

// function that find max from a given array
void *min(void *size)
{
    int i, j, min;
    dim *b = (dim *)size;
    min =((dim*)size) -> mat[b -> s][0]; //set the first element as minimum

    // finding max
    for(i = b -> s; i < b -> e; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if(min > ((dim*)size) -> mat[i][j])
                min = ((dim*)size) -> mat[i][j];
        }
    }

    // storing max from first half of
    // 2-d array into 0th index
    if(b -> s == 0)
        minf[0] = min;

    // storing max from second half of
    // 2-d array into 1st index
    else
    minf[1] = min;
}

// driver function
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    dim *sth;
    sth = (dim *)malloc(sizeof(dim));


    //input for array size and number of threads
    printf("Type n and p\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&(sth->n), &(sth->p));

    pthread_t thread[sth->p];

    //fill the array
    for(i = 0; i < sth -> n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j< sth -> n; j++)
        {
            printf("Type element\n");
            scanf("%d",&(sth->mat[i][j]));
        }
    }  

    //create the threads
    for (int j = 0; j < sth->p; j++)
    {
        int thread_part = part++;
        sth->s = thread_part * (sth -> n / sth -> p);
        sth -> e = (thread_part + 1) * ((sth -> n) / (sth -> p));
        pthread_create(&thread[j], NULL, min, (void *)sth);
    }

    //waiting for threads to complete
    for (int j = 0; j < sth->p; j++)
    {
        pthread_join(thread[j], NULL);
    }  

    //find the smallest out of all the arrays
    int smallest = sth -> mat[0][0];
    for(j = 0; j < sth -> p; j++)
    {
        if(minf[j] < minf[j+1])
        smallest = minf[j];
    }

     printf("Min is %d\n" ,smallest);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `minf` declaration missing as in `minf[0] = min;`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: he means, in your code you did not declare the array `minf`

Comment: it is declared in the struct so it can be used in every part of the code

Comment: user47 What C compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using gcc, in linux

Comment: My gcc reports "error: 'minf' undeclared (first use in this function);"  I suspect what code you have here us not the true code you compiled.

Comment: if `minf` is declared in the struct, for example, `dim * b`, you have to use `b` to call it: `b[i].minf` or `b->minf`

Comment: `typedef struct dim
{
    ... int minf[100]; 
}dim;` only defines a type, not an object.  Try compiling the code you have posted.  Enable all warnings to see things like `void* min(void *size)` missing a return.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, however, i don't get any warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main()`:

```
    //create the threads
    for (int j = 0; j < sth->p; j++)
    {
        int thread_part = part++;
        sth->s = thread_part * (sth -> n / sth -> p);
        sth -> e = (thread_part + 1) * ((sth -> n) / (sth -> p));
        pthread_create(&thread[j], NULL, min, (void *)sth);
    }
```

1. `part` is declared `static int part = 0 ;`.  I cannot find any other use of `part`.

   So `thread_part` appears to be the same as `j` -- and `part` is entirely redundant.  That doesn't stop the code working... it's just very nasty.
2. there is one `dim *sth;`

   Each time you create a thread, `sth->s` and `sth->e` are set to tell the thread which part of `sth->mat[][]` to process.  BUT all threads receive a `sth` :-(  [Each thread needs it's *own* `sth->s` and `sth->e` values !!]
3. you have a problem if `sth->n` does not exactly divide by `sth->p`.

In `min()`:

4. you set `dim *b = (dim *)size;` but then use a mixture of `b->` and `((dim *)size)->`, which is a mess.
5. the `for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)` should surely be `j < b->n` ??
6. this:

   ```
   // storing max from first half of
   // 2-d array into 0th index
   if(b -> s == 0)
       minf[0] = min;

   // storing max from second half of
   // 2-d array into 1st index
   else
   minf[1] = min;
   ```

   is nonsense.  Each thread needs to know which `minf[]` to fill in.

To fix all this you need to pass to each thread:

1. its *own* `sth->s` and `sth->e`
2. its index for `minf[]`

   Actually... if we call this `ti`, each thread can calculate its own `sth->s` and `sth->e` from `ti`, `sth->n` and `sth->p`.

---

Suggestion.

```
enum { max_n = 100 } ;

// Structure to encapsulate matrix.

typedef struct
{
   int n ;
   int body[max_n][max_n] ;
} mat_t ;

// Structure for each thread

typedef struct
{
  pthread_t thrid ;         // for join
  int  s, e ;               // process columns s..e-1
  const mat_t* mat ;        // shared data -- the matrix
  int  min ;                // return value
} thr_data_t ;

...
int main()
{
  ...
  mat_t* mat ;
  int   p ;

  mat = malloc(sizeof(mat_t));

  //input for array size and number of threads
  printf("Type n and p\n");
  scanf("%d %d", &(mat->n), &p) ;    // expect mat->n in 0..100, p in 1..??

  ...

  //create the threads
  thr_data_t  thrd[p] ;   // all threads joined before goes out of scope
  int s = 0 ;
  int c = mat->n / p ;
  int r = mat->n % p ;
  for (int j = 0 ; j < p ; j++)
    {
      int cr, e ;

      cr = (r != 0) ;
      e  = s + c + cr ;

      thrd[j].s = s ;
      thrd[j].e = e ;
      thrd[j].mat = mat ;
      pthread_create(&thrd[j].thrid, NULL, min, (void*)&thrd[j]);

      s  = e ;
      r -= cr ;
    } ;
  ...

  for (int j = 0; j < p; j++)
    {
      pthread_join(thrd[j].thrid, NULL);

      int tmin = thrd[j].min ;      // min found by jth thread
      ...
    } ;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so you mean that I should create another ti pointer ?

Comment: You need to think about what information needs to be passed to each thread, some of which (eg `ti`) is unique to each thread, and some of which (eg `mat[][]` etc) is shared by the threads.  You might need a new `struct` which contains those two sets of information, and a separate instance of that `struct` for each thread.

Comment: Ok I see, however, I don't quite get it

Comment: Well, I have added a suggestion.  I decided `ti` is not that useful.  But the key thing is the `thr_data_t` struct, which encapsulates everything about each thread... I think of it as a message sent from the main thread to each worker thread, which it sends back when it has finished.  This is a reasonable model for most "divide a body of work between 'n' threads" problems.  [A little more work is required if you want to pick up the return value from each thread as soon as it terminates.]